# Native iOS navigation on React-Native View Component button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have a simple React-Native component`ReactNativeMasterView` with a button I want to use for native navigation.

in `ReactNativeMasterView`:

```
var MasterViewController = NativeModules.MasterViewController
```

then the button calls:

```
MasterViewController.buttonEvent()
```

I have a basic Obj-C view controller called `MasterViewController`

In `MasterViewController.h`:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <RCTBridgeModule>
```

And in `MasterViewController.m` 
I have a reference to the react native view in my storyboard:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet RNMasterView *reactViewWrapper;
```

and native module and method look like this:

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(buttonEvent) {

    RCTLogInfo(@"Button Pressed");

    UIViewController *detail = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [rootViewController showViewController:detail sender:self];
    });

}
```

It almost works too...

Sadly the transition takes me to a black screen, and when i inspect the view hierarchy it looks like `UITransitionView` is just presenting an empty `View` I can actually navigate back from this state too.

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

UPDATE:

I can make it work with a UIAlertController:

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:name
                             message:param
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    NSLog(@"Cancel");
}];

[alert addAction:cancelAction];


UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated: YES completion: nil];
});
```

that appears to work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's black because you're `initializing` a `viewController` programmatically and push it `UIViewController *detail = [[UIViewController alloc]init];`.

Try this:

```
UIViewController *detail = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
detail.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**EDIT**

You shouldn't really be `initializing` view controllers like that unless you need to. You should be using `storyboards` for creating view controllers and laying out the views and then presenting them onto a `UINavigationViewController`. Here is a good [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/).

Comment: It has been a while since I have done iOS development, thanks for the reminder!  I used storyboards and `[rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:nil];` which did the trick.